# How Google maps addListener give us a global click event?

Tags: google-maps, events, google-maps-markers

I'm starter and sorry for my poor English.

Summery: I have two events:
**google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e)**
and
**google.maps.event.addListener(mpolygon, 'click', function(e)**
But I want both of them together. Something like this:
***google.maps.event.addListener(map, mpolygon 'click', function(e)***

Explanation:
I have developed a very simple program to understand Google maps better.

This code uses geometry library. We have a polygon on the map. When we click on the map the program creates a green circle marker on the map. But when we click on the polygon it should creates a red circle marker on the polygon. My problem is that When I click on the map it creates a green circle on the map because we have "google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e)" But for create red marker on the polygon we have to change "google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e)" to "google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle, 'click', function(e)"
I want both of them. I mean when I click on the map or on the bermudaTriangle both of them works.

I need something like this:
"google.maps.event.addListener(map, bermudaTriangle, 'click', function(e)"

Here is my source that just have one event.addListener and we can just click on the map to create green marker but I want it to have two event.addListener for map and for polygon:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
var result;

if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, bermudaTriangle)) {
  result = 'red';
}
else
{
  result = 'green';
}

var circle = {
  path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
  fillColor: result,
  fillOpacity: .9,
  strokeColor: 'white',
  strokeWeight: .9,
  scale: 10
};

new google.maps.Marker({
  position: e.latLng,
  map: map,
  icon: circle
})

 });
```

Comment: I'm confused. Why don't you add a click listener to the polygon that adds red markers and one to the map that adds green markers?

Comment: Because they are exactly same so I prefer to do it.

Comment: and maybe I need to create a lot of polygon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have 2 options:

1. set the `clickable`-option of the `bermudaTriangle` to `false`  . `click`-events on the polygon will no longer be captured and your current script will work as expected.
2. use only the listener for `map` and trigger a click on the map when you click on the `bermudaTriangle`:

   ```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e,color) {

     color=color||'green'

     var circle = {
       path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
       fillColor: color,
       fillOpacity: .9,
       strokeColor: 'white',
       strokeWeight: .9,
       scale: 10
     };

     new google.maps.Marker({
       position: e.latLng,
       map: map,
       icon: circle
     })
   ```

   });

   ```
   google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle, 'click', function(e) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map,'click',e,'red')
   });
   ```

As you see the listener for the map-click now has a 2nd argument `color` .
When you click on the map, this argument is `undefined` (and defaults to `green`). When you click on the bermudaTriangle the argument is `red` .

The 2nd solution should be preferable when you need to apply this for multiple polygons, because you don't need to check  if the latLng intersects any polygon.